# copy sheet and cell value based on list and rename as per list with excel vba code

Tags: excel, vba

i am very new to vba , currently i am looking for code to copy cell values from list to multiple sheet in specific cell

what i am trying to do is as per bellow sheet "point" i have a list with values column B are the names and C & D are values

i need to copy sheet named "template" and rename as per the values in Column B and the values are un defined and be upto any length
[list sheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oW6Bs.png)

[template](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7B4d8.png)

currently i am using bellow code to copy sheet and rename as per list

```
Sub CopySheetRenameFromCell()

Dim sh1 As Worksheet, sh2 As Worksheet, c As Range
Set sh1 = Sheets("template")
Set sh2 = Sheets("point")
For Each c In sh2.Range("B6", sh2.Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp))
sh1.Copy After:=Sheets(Sheets.Count)
On Error Resume Next
ActiveSheet.Name = c.Value:
On Error GoTo 0
Next
End Sub
```

[result sheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EEKfq.png)

but i have no idea how can i copy value from "point" Sheet Column C and D values 1 & 51 to sheet "a" Column C2 and F2 and so on

a values in sheet "a"
b values in sheet "b" and on

awaiting your help

Comment: ok this code looks fine, is it all working?  what else specifically do you need it to?

Comment: Could you share the screenshots of some nice worksheets with more data so we can understand what needs to be done? I mean, the *list sheet* is too simplified, and the *result sheet* is the same as the *template*. You can [edit your post](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/72835495/edit) at any time.

Comment: Do you mean that after it create the new sheet mentioned in sheet "point", you want to put a value to each newly created sheet with the value mentioned in sheet "point" ? Example : the newly created sheet "a", cell C2 will have value 1 and cell F2 value will be 51 ---> this value is coming from sheet point C6 and D6 where B6 value is "a". The newly created sheet "b", cell C2 value is 2 and F2 value is 52 ---> coming from sheet point C7 and D7 where B7 value is "b". Please CMIIW.

Comment: @karma  Yes I am looking for this code

Comment: @abbh01, after this line `ActiveSheet.Name = c.Value`, maybe try to have `activesheet.range("C2").value = c.offset(0,1).value : activesheet.range("F2").value = c.offset(0,2).value`. Not tested in my side.

Answer (score 0):

### Copy Template Worksheet

- This is a basic code. It assumes that each of the cells of the range `B6:BLastRow` contains a valid value for naming a worksheet. It also assumes that each of the worksheets to be created does not exist already.

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub CopySheetRenameFromCell()

    ' Reference the workbook ('wb').
    Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook ' workbook containing this code
    
    ' Reference the source worksheet ('sws').
    Dim sws As Worksheet: Set sws = wb.Worksheets("Point")
    
    ' Calculate the source last row ('slRow'),
    ' the row of the last non-empty cell in the column.
    Dim slRow As Long
    slRow = sws.Cells(sws.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row
    
    ' Reference the template worksheets ('tws').
    Dim tws As Worksheet: Set tws = wb.Worksheets("Template")
    
    ' Declare additional variables.
    Dim dws As Worksheet ' Current Destination (Copied) Worksheet
    Dim sr As Long ' Current Row in the Source Worksheet
    
    ' Loop through the rows of the source worksheet.
    For sr = 6 To slRow
         ' Create a copy of the template worksheet after the last sheet
         ' in the workbook.
         tws.Copy After:=wb.Sheets(wb.Sheets.Count)
         ' Reference this copy, the destination worksheet,
         ' which is the last (work)sheet in the workbook.
         Set dws = wb.Sheets(wb.Sheets.Count)
         ' Rename the destination worksheet.
         dws.Name = sws.Cells(sr, "B").Value
         ' Write the values from columns 'C' and 'D' in the row ('r')
         ' of the source worksheet to the cells `C2` and `F2` respectively
         ' in the destination worksheet.
         dws.Range("C2").Value = sws.Cells(sr, "C").Value
         dws.Range("F2").Value = sws.Cells(sr, "D").Value
    Next sr
    
    ' Save the workbook.
    'wb.Save
    
    ' Inform.
    MsgBox "Point worksheets created.", vbInformation
    
End Sub
```

Comment: can you please help is sorting one more issue with same sheet

Comment: i have few more data in point sheet from column  E:G  but some of this rows has data and some not  , all column E : G has header  and problem here is i need to copy the cell in each column E:G which has data and paste it in destination worksheet  in column A and specific row from say 4-10 but bellow each other with those having data